# Mysql search for keyword with white space

Tags: php

Good day, I have a problem which this thing doesn't work for me and I have no more idea to do this that's why I am here.

I have this query:

```
mysqli_query($sqlcon,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `keyword` REGEXP ' $userpost '");
```

`$sqlcon` is the db connection

I just want to get the keyword with white space beside, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried it with the `%` wildcards? `WHERE keyword LIKE '% %'`

Comment: [be sure `$userpost` is sanitized and escaped](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: i am searching for multiple keyword sir thats why I didn't use LIKE ''% %

Comment: So is $userpost an array of keywords?

Comment: it is in keyword1|keyword2|keyword3 sir

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need parentheses:

```
mysqli_query($sqlcon,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `keyword` REGEXP ' ($userpost) '");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need regex.  If you are doing simple string matching, you may use the `%` as a wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `keyword` like '%$userpost%'
```

Comment: i am searching for mulitple keywords sir